# Using 2 different ViewModels in a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Can you use 2 different ViewModels in a Grid?

One ViewModel to fill a ComboBox and another ViewModel to get the selectedItem?

Like this sample (not working):

```
<Grid Grid.Row="4"
      DataContext="{Binding ViewModel1, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
            Text="Language:"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Width="200"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageList}"
            DataContext="{Binding ViewModel2, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify an explicit source for each binding:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="4">
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
                Text="Language:"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="200"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel1.LanguageList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel2.SelectedLanguage, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
</Grid>
```